# Remove and capture text from a string

Tags: php

I have seen many similar questions but nothing is working for my requirement.

I have a string

`<p><strong>Consider the following reaction,</strong></p>\n<p>~~1~~</p>`.

I want to remove this **~~some no.~~** from string and get string value in **var1** and get the number between **~~ ~~** in **var2**

How will I do this using PHP?

My expected result:

```
str3 = <p><strong>Consider the following reaction,</strong></p>\n<p></p>
str4 = 1
```

I am trying this code so far:

```
$str  = 'This is a text, "Your Balance left $0.10", End 0';
$str2="<p><strong>Consider the following reaction,</strong></p>\n<p>~~1~~</p>";;


if (preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $str, $m)) {
    print $m[1];   
} else {

}

//Unable to understand what do I do in below in below code to fetch my desired result
if (preg_match('/~~([^"]+)~~/', $str2, $m2)) {
print $m2[1];    
} else {

}
```

Comment: __Explain__ the difference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782360/how-do-i-remove-some-no-from-my-text-string?

Comment: that is closed, Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one....so i asked a new one, please let someone help me

Comment: Yes, it was closed. Now, this question is closed __too__ and unless you have a __serious reason__ to ask same or similar questions, all such questions will be closed.

Comment: Why you are not allowing someone to reply, i need help on that

Comment: this is not working for me if (preg_match('/~~([^"]+)~~/', $str2, $m2)) {

Comment: Not working is a __too broad__ reason. Not working how - your pc explodes? your browser crashes? or what?